# What's wrong with my JTextField?

Tags: java, user-input, jtextfield

I'm attempting to make an application for a small game, and I'm currently having an issue of getting my code to work. It should be displaying a window with a text field, a jbutton, and an uneditable text field. I need to get it to read what I put into the first text field. However when I run it all I receive is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
string: "Enter Command"

at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
at TextAdv.<init>(TextAdv.java:16)
at TextAdv.main(TextAdv.java:43)
```

I'm not exactly great at reading errors and I've been trying to figure this out for an hour or so. If someone could please help me fix this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAdv {

    JFrame jtfMainFrame;
    JButton jbnButton2;
    JTextField jtfInput, jtfCommand;
    JPanel jplPanel, jplPanel2;
    public TextAdv() {
        jtfMainFrame = new JFrame("TextAdv");
        jbnButton2 = new JButton("Quit (LEAVES GAME)");
        jtfInput = new JTextField(55);
        jtfCommand = new JTextField("Enter Command", 40);
        double command = Double.parseDouble(jtfCommand.getText());
        jplPanel = new JPanel();
        jplPanel2 = new JPanel();
        jbnButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        jtfInput.setEditable(false);
        jplPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jplPanel.add(jtfCommand);
        jplPanel.add(jbnButton2);
        jplPanel2.add(jtfInput);
        jtfMainFrame.getContentPane().add(jplPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jtfMainFrame.getContentPane().add(jplPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jtfMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtfMainFrame.pack();
        jtfMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                    .getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        TextAdv application = new TextAdv();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read the javadocs for the [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField(java.lang.String,%20int)) The first column is the text, which can not be converted to a double - as error message states

Comment: The text in the field is `Enter Command`, which is obviously not a number. You're thinking in a procedural manner, which is not how GUIs work, they work in an event driven manner, something happens you respond to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I be able to use a string input instead of a number? I'm super new to all this J Whatever stuff, and I'm trying my best with it. Apologies in advance if this is a relatively easy predicament.

Comment: `JTextField` will only deal with `String` values. At some point in the future, you need to get the value from the text field and convert it, this may cause an error, which you need to be ready to handle. `JTextField` supports the `ActionListener` API, but you could also use another button. A more complicated solution would be to use a `JFormattedTextField`, but you might find that a little over your head

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse value of the `jtfCommand` field which is `"Enter Command"`:

```
double command = Double.parseDouble(jtfCommand.getText());
```

This line throws `NumberFormatException` if `jtfCommand.getText()` returns a String that is not a number.

You should be aware that the following line of code creates `JTextField` instance with the text value initialized to the first argument ([Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JTextField.java#JTextField.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) ):

```
jtfCommand = new JTextField("Enter Command", 40);
```

And when you are calling `jtfCommand.getText()` it returns `"Enter Command"` that is obviously not a number.

Comment: I think I found another way to do what I was trying, and you explained to me why it was doing what it was, Thanks!